# How do I escape the "<" and ">" characters?

Tags: apex, escape

```
if(String.isNotEmpty(orderItem.Nickname_2__c)){
notes += '<p><strong>Nickname 2:</strong> ' + orderItem.Nickname_2__c + '</p>';
```

I've a class that collects input from a few text fields, slaps some formatting on it, and concatenates into a rich text field.

Sometimes one of the text fields - e.g. Nickname 2 - has something like < Ducky > but minus the spaces between the < and the D and the y and the >. While it shows up fine in the text field, once it goes through apex concatenation, it doesn't show up in the rich text field.

I tried a formula field that adds a \ in front of the < and > but then only the \ shows up in the rich text field.

```
SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( Nickname_2__c , "<", "\\<" ), ">", "\\>")
```

Is it possible to get the < and > to show up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `String.escapeHTML4` method:

```java
notes += '<p><strong>Nickname 2:</strong> ' + 
    orderItem.Nickname_2__c.escapeHTML4() +
    '</p>';
```

This will take care of characters like `<`, `>`, and `&` for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, though I had to write it a little differently: `notes += '<p><strong>Nickname 2:</strong> ' + orderItem.Nickname_2__c.escapeHTML4() + '</p>';`

Comment: @Lawson Ah, right. It's been a while since I've used it. I'll edit it.